# Applying the same `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` every time to a component without reusing code

Tags: reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

I have the following `Modal` component rendering inside a `ReactCSSTransitionGroup`:

```
<ReactCSSTransitionGroup
  transitionName="modalTransition"
  transitionEnterTimeout={500}
  transitionLeaveTimeout={500}
  transitionAppearTimeout={500}
  transitionAppear
>
   <Modal />
</ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
```

This works fine, but I want to apply my transition every time I render a `Modal`.

As I understand it, I can't place the `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` inside the `Modal` component because it needs to have rendered before that.

What can I do to ensure the `Modal` always has the `modalTransition` `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` without repeating the wrapping code every single time I call it?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html#animating-one-or-zero-items

You can put the `<ReactCSSTransitionGroup>` inside the `<Modal>` and just change the key property on "transition change"